# Referencing other class objects and variables

Tags: c#, xml, pointers, reference

I'm very new to c#, and this is probably a very noob and simple question, and I'll try my best to explain what the problem is:

I am struggling to "reference" variables between classes... Let me explain the situation and what I need to do:

I have a "Node" class, which contains a heap of variables such as 'Name', 'Length', XCoordinate', 'YCoordinate', 'Node Type' - They are all Strings which I am reading from an XML file.

I also have a "NodeLinkage" class with a bunch of string variables also (also read from an XML file) such as 'Length', 'TrackType' blah blah blah.

Problem: I am gathering this data from an XML file, and am required to write two text files (one for Node, one for Links (NodeLinkage)). The NodeLinkage file is also required to have some of the same information that is in the Node file (such as a "NodeAName" and "NodeBName" - two of the 'Node' object names). I was hoping there is some way I could use 'pointers' (or something similar) in each 'NodeLinkage' that would reference these particular Nodes... And therefore storing the names (and any other variables required) much easier...

These XML files have up to 5000 nodes, and huge numbers of links, and the XML files is read so that the Nodes data is all read first, then the link data.

What is the best way to store this information (Nodes and NodeLinkages) when read (Lists/map/dictionary) and how do I use something like 'pointers' to refer to a particular Node / NodeName from a Link.

---

EDIT!:

Thankyou to those who have replied so far! Here is a sample of the XML file that is being read:

```
<Nodes>
    <Node Name="WAI2" LongName="Waitara" Length="100" NodeType="6" ... (other attributes)>
        <NodeMasterTimingPoint NodeName="WAI1"></NodeMasterTimingPoint>
    </Node>
    <Node Name="WAI3" LongName="Waitara" Length="100" NodeType="6" ... (other attributes)>
        <NodeMasterTimingPoint NodeName="WAI1"></NodeMasterTimingPoint>
    </Node>
    .... other nodes
</Nodes>

<Links>
    <Link NodeAName="WAI1" NodeBName="WAI2" Length="200" TrackType="37" SBId="10482">
    </Link>
    ... more links
</Links>
```

Each of the Node/Link records have around 15-20 attributes.

As you can see, the Link record uses two 'NodeXName's... I was wondering whether there is any way to reference or 'point' to these two nodes, and therefore when printing the Link data somehting like NodeA.Name could be used. Therefore other data such as NodeA.Length could also be used if required.

```
Node Class:

class cNode
{
    public string Name;
    public string LongName;
    public string PlatformName;
    public string NodeType;
    public string Length;
    public string MasterTimingNode;
    public string MasterJunctionNode;
    public string[] PenaltyFromNode;
    public string[] PenaltyToNode;
    public string[] Penalty;
    public string PFMORI;
    public string XCRD;
    public string YCRD;
    public string PlanLocation;

    // Few methods which aren't important
    public string GetDataString()
    {
    ...
    }

}
```

The NodeLinkage class is very similar to the above Node class.

I also have a "main" class with the main method, which will simply read the XML file and assign values to each of the Node/Links - not sure on how to store each of these though?? List? Map?

As mentioned before, the Node data is read and stored (therefore Node objects are created) before the Link data is even read..

Thanks again,
Nick.

SOrry for the HUGE amount of stuff to read. :P

Comment: I think it would be easier to help you if we have your class/xml structure here to see.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to just add a variable of type 'Node' to your NodeLinkage class and then assign it when you are reading your XML file

Then all the relevant node information will be available to the NodeLinkage class via a reference to the corresponding node

I suppose it depends on how many nodes a node linkage can reference, you can hard code a couple of refs e.g.

```
class NodeLinkage 
{
    public Node NodeA { get; set; }
    public Node NobeB { get; set; }
}
```

Or hold a dict/list

```
class NodeLinkage 
{
    public List<Node> Nodes { get; set; }
}
```

Also sounds like you need to build your node listing

```
List<Node> Nodes = new List<Node>();
// Read node data
Nodes = SomeRoutineThatGetsThem();

List<NodeLinkage> Links = new List<NodeLinkage>();
// Read link data
Links = SomeRoutineThatGetsThem2();

// Create node linkage refs
foreach(var link in Links) 
{
    // Find the nodes that should be associated with this link - maybe using Linq?
    var assocNodes = Nodes.Where(n => n.NodeID == link.NodeID); // No idea what your setup is so this is a random pseudo code bit!
    // blah - assign etc
}
```

Is this useful to you so far?

Comment: I don't think so, because I read all the node data first... so therefore the nodes will have to be created before the NodeLinkage objects are right?..

anyway, more information has been added to the original post (XML file and Node class) cheers.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, "NodeType" would be an attribute of a "Node". However it is not clear what the relationship between a "Node" and a "NodeLinkage" is. I suspect this NodeLinkage is really just a way of dealing with the relationship between objects during serialization/deserialization (in case those words haven't been explained to you yet, serialization is the process of taking a set of objects in memory and persisting them to files and/or databases; deserialization is creating a set of objects from files and/or databases).

Objects in memory ("object instances") will have references to other objects; for example, your "Node" might have only a single NodeType, or it might have multiple NodeTypes. Either way, as far as your instance of a Node is concerned, NodeType (or NodeTypes) is simply a reference to another object. It doesn't matter if one or a hundred nodes all share the same node type; they will all point to the same NodeType instance -- you won't have a hundred nodes with a hundred NodeType instances.

However, when the time comes to serialize, to avoid duplicating a bunch of NodeType entries, you will want to be able to abstract a NodeType with an identifier (you will often see this called an Identity property). Before we get to the solution, let's take a look at our class structures and how they would serialize:

```
    public class NodeManager
    {
        public List<Node> Nodes { get; set; }
    }

    public class Node
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<NodeType> NodeTypes{ get; set; }
        public int Length { get; set; }
        public int XCoordinate { get; set; }
        public int YCoordinate { get; set; }
    }

    public class NodeType
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string SomeOtherNodeTypeProperty { get; set; }
        public string YetAnotherNodeTypeProperty { get; set; }
    }
```

In this object model, the NodeManager class serves as your in-memory repository for all of the Nodes that have been instantiated. This is the class you will serialize from, or deserialize to. It contains a collection of Nodes, and nothing else. In a more detailed model, it will probably contain methods to create, add, delete and query the Node collection in useful ways, but for the purposes of discussing ser/deser this is enough.

As you can see, a Node object can have multiple types. If we were to create ten thousand Nodes in memory, each with a few types, we would have a massive duplication of the NodeType XML nodes in the written file, because the serializer has no way to abstract a NodeType instance into a reference to a NodeType. Our XML file will look something like this (not precisely like this; I did this by hand):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Nodes>
    <Node>
        <Name>Foo</Name>
        <Length>5</Length>
        <XCoordinate>24</XCoordinate>
        <YCoordinate>36</YCoordinate>
        <NodeTypes>
            <NodeType>
                <Name>Type 1</Name>
                <SomeOtherNodeTypeProperty>Blah</SomeOtherNodeTypeProperty>
                <YetAnotherNodeTypeProperty>Meh</YetAnotherNodeTypeProperty>
            </NodeType>
            <NodeType>
                <Name>Type 2</Name>
                <SomeOtherNodeTypeProperty>Foo</SomeOtherNodeTypeProperty>
                <YetAnotherNodeTypeProperty>Bar</YetAnotherNodeTypeProperty>
            </NodeType>
            <NodeType>
                <Name>Type 3</Name>
                <SomeOtherNodeTypeProperty>Fizz</SomeOtherNodeTypeProperty>
                <YetAnotherNodeTypeProperty>Buzz</YetAnotherNodeTypeProperty>
            </NodeType>
        </NodeTypes>
    </Node>
    <Name>Bar</Name>
    <Length>15</Length>
    <XCoordinate>224</XCoordinate>
    <YCoordinate>336</YCoordinate>
    <NodeTypes>
        <NodeType>
            <Name>Type 1</Name>
            <SomeOtherNodeTypeProperty>Blah</SomeOtherNodeTypeProperty>
            <YetAnotherNodeTypeProperty>Meh</YetAnotherNodeTypeProperty>
        </NodeType>
        <NodeType>
            <Name>Type 2</Name>
            <SomeOtherNodeTypeProperty>Foo</SomeOtherNodeTypeProperty>
            <YetAnotherNodeTypeProperty>Bar</YetAnotherNodeTypeProperty>
        </NodeType>
        <NodeType>
            <Name>Type 3</Name>
            <SomeOtherNodeTypeProperty>Fizz</SomeOtherNodeTypeProperty>
            <YetAnotherNodeTypeProperty>Buzz</YetAnotherNodeTypeProperty>
        </NodeType>
    </NodeTypes>
    </Node>
</Nodes>
```

Notice how the two nodes each support 3 Node types, and they are complete duplicates of each other. To avoid this we can add a NodeTypeID property. This is simply a value that is guarenteed to be unique across all NodeType instances. When we have that, instead of having to write out an entire NodeType, we can just write it's ID, and from the ID we can get to the rest of the information about a NodeType. Let's add a new property to our NodeType :

```
public class NodeType
{
    public int NodeTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SomeOtherNodeTypeProperty { get; set; }
    public string YetAnotherNodeTypeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Now that there is a NodeTypeID property when we serialize our nodes, it looks a lot cleaner:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NodeRoot>
    <Nodes>
        <Node>
            <Name>Foo</Name>
            <Length>5</Length>
            <XCoordinate>24</XCoordinate>
            <YCoordinate>36</YCoordinate>
            <NodeTypes>
                <NodeType NodeTypeId="1"/>
                <NodeType NodeTypeId="2"/>
                <NodeType NodeTypeId="3"/>
            </NodeTypes>
        </Node>
        <Node>
            <Name>Bar</Name>
            <Length>15</Length>
            <XCoordinate>224</XCoordinate>
            <YCoordinate>336</YCoordinate>
            <NodeTypes>
                <NodeType NodeTypeId="1"/>
                <NodeType NodeTypeId="2"/>
                <NodeType NodeTypeId="3"/>
            </NodeTypes>
        </Node>
    </Nodes>
    <NodeTypes>
        <NodeType>
            <Name>Type 1</Name>
            <SomeOtherNodeTypeProperty>Blah</SomeOtherNodeTypeProperty>
            <YetAnotherNodeTypeProperty>Meh</YetAnotherNodeTypeProperty>
        </NodeType>
        <NodeType>
            <Name>Type 2</Name>
            <SomeOtherNodeTypeProperty>Foo</SomeOtherNodeTypeProperty>
            <YetAnotherNodeTypeProperty>Bar</YetAnotherNodeTypeProperty>
        </NodeType>
        <NodeType>
            <Name>Type 3</Name>
            <SomeOtherNodeTypeProperty>Fizz</SomeOtherNodeTypeProperty>
            <YetAnotherNodeTypeProperty>Buzz</YetAnotherNodeTypeProperty>
        </NodeType>
    </NodeTypes>
</NodeRoot>
```

This is getting pretty long so I'll wrap it here; hopefully I've given you the direction you're looking for.